# Opencv Why Can Not Open Video from Spherical Camera (from 360 angle camera)

Tags: c++, opencv, video, camera

I have a video file from camera( which 360 angle ) I want to open this video file and than separating frame but I cant open this video file On the other hand  I can open another video file which from vebcam not 360 angle camera 
My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    int counter;
VideoCapture cap("out.avi"); 
    if( !cap.isOpened()){
         cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
         return -1;
    }

    double count = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); //get the frame count
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,count-1); //Set index to last frame
    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   Mat frame;
    while(1)
    {
      stringstream file;   
        bool success = cap.read(frame); 
        if (!success){
          cout << "Cannot read  frame " << endl;
          break;
        }
        file << "C:\\" << counter << ".png";
        counter++;
       // imshow("MyVideo", frame);
        imwrite(file.str(),frame);
       // if(waitKey(0) == 27) break;


    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Omg! Video can opened ! but  Now I have this message Cannot read frame and I have just frame (I have only one image after seperate frame )

Comment: Are you using the camera somewhere else, besides your program, while it is still running?

Comment: No I am not using camrea desşdes my program

Comment: `cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,count-1); //Set index to last frame` --> Does this line make it so that you can read only one frame?

Comment: hmm I tried this code for another video and I get the all frames so I think  this line  cannot be reason